# Why transparent PNG bigger than white background?

Tags: linux, image, imagemagick, png

I am trying to convert an image (just a signature) down to the smallest possible size... I thought setting it transparent would yield smaller file size but is not...

```
convert -resize 300 -threshold 50% -colors 2 -transparent white -alpha remove sig.png -trim test.png
```

The above command yield about 1200 bytes. Removing the alpha essentially just setting the background to white.

```
convert -resize 300 -threshold 50% -colors 2 -transparent white sig.png -trim test1.png
```

This made the background transparent, but the file size is about 1900 bytes.

Is there a way to just tell the command to store only black color and nothing else?

Comment: png doesn't have "background" color. it has an alpha channel. if you create an alpha-enabled png, you're using 4bytes/pixel (RGBA) instead of 3 bytes (RGB).

Comment: Ok, so I guess running it with `-colors 2` (without any of those `-transparent white` or `-alpha remove`) is really the smallest I could get?

Comment: Try saving it as a GIF maybe - that can do transparency too. And is palettised, so quite small.

Comment: It may help to use PNG8 format (change the output filename to "PNG8:frank_sig.png").  This will force "convert" to write an indexed-color PNG with a 2-color PLTE chunk and 1-entry tRNS chunk.

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson Just tried it, and actually ended up with bigger size. Using `PNG8:` or `PNG32:` yield bigger size than `PNG:` or no PNG prefix. Weird.